# Mat* input for Cvknearest

Tags: opencv

as we know CvKnearest neighbor get input in this manner

`CvKNearest::CvKNearest(const Mat& trainData, const Mat& responses, const Mat&     sampleIdx=Mat(), bool isRegression=false, int max_k=32 )`

or in this manner

`CvKNearest::CvKNearest(const CvMat* trainData, const CvMat* responses, const CvMat* sampleIdx=0, bool isRegression=false, int max_k=32 )`

But I have two cv::Mat* for trainData and response. how can i convert them to match one of these two input format for CvKnearest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dereference the pointers you have and use the first one.

For example, if you have `cv::Mat* myTrainData` and `cv::Mat* myResponses`, then:

```
CvKNearest::CvKNearest(*myTrainData, *myResponses, const Mat& sampleIdx=Mat(), bool isRegression=false, int max_k=32 )
```